# Selenium-JavaMail api-Unable to perform email verification. It throws error as :- Please log in via your web browser:

Tags: selenium-webdriver, email

I use java mail API in selenium automation script to verify email confirmations. The scripts will be executed by different team members. I got this error, when someone tries to run from other IP address.

```
Web login required: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754
```

while using "pop3" protocol
and

```
Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/accounts/answer/78754 (Failure)
```

while using imaps protocol

Answer (score 0):

You should allow access from untrusted clients in your Google account settings. Find the details by the link you have provided in your question.

Comment: 1) lesssecureapps-> Turned on                                                                                    2) Never show an alert for unusual activity->Turned ON                                               3) 2-Step Verification-> OFF                                                                                          4)POP -> Enabled for all mail                                                                                       5) IMAP ->Enabled                                     
But still i am facing this issue.